# Why is my Colorado Blue Spruce Dying?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, tree-care

Everything seemed to be green and fine until a couple weeks ago. As you can see in these pictures, the branches seem to be losing their needles in patterns and turning gray, leaving the lower branches empty. It is cold, but nothing was like this last year. What's wrong with it?
[image: blue spruce in distress]

[image: blue spruce dropping needles]

Comment: Where do you live in the world?

Comment: Where, how long since planted, what source ( pot grown, dug up, etc), how has it been cared for? Guess just not enough water.

Comment: @Jurp I am in Texas, so Zone 8B.

Comment: @blacksmith37 It is by itself in the backyard, it was pot grown but I planted it in the ground (bought it last Christmas). It receives weekly watering although it's been raining more often in Texas every day now so I thought that was enough since the peat/clay soil holds water for a long time.

Comment: TX zone 8 is too warm for spruce ( also where I live). In Alberta, I have seen black, white and Alberta spruces happy in a bog, so water should not be a problem.

Comment: @blacksmith37 I have heard it is too warm here, but strangely it has only deteoriated once the cold weather hit - it was perfectly fine in the 100 degree summer.